# How to sort boxplots based on median in R

Tags: r

I need to sort the 9 boxplots based on smallest to largest mean. Here is the code I have so far.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("aloraine/loralib")
library(loralib)
genes=getGeneLengthsForPanel()
medians=getMedianGeneLengthsForPanel(genes)
sizes=getGenomeSizesForPanel()/10**6
main="Gene length and genome size"
xlab="genome sizes (Mb)"
ylab="log10(median gene length)"
xlim=c(0,4000)
plot(medians~sizes,pch=16,xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,las=1,col="lightblue",main=main,xlim=xlim)
text(medians~sizes,labels=names(medians),cex=0.9,font=2,pos=4)
old.par=par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mar=c(5.1,7.5,4.1,2.1))
boxplot(log10length~species,data=genes,las=1,horizontal=TRUE,xlab=ylab)
par(old.par)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code before doing your boxplot and it should reorder the species according to its median value. If you prefer to order using the means, you need just to substitute `median` for `mean` in the `aggregate` function.

```
#Calculate the median for each species
medians_order<-aggregate(x = genes$log10length,                
          by = list(as.character(genes$species)),              
          FUN = median)  

#Order species by median value
medians_order<-medians_order$Group.1[order(medians_order$x, decreasing = T)]

#Reorder species as a factor according to their medians values order
genes$species<-factor(as.character(genes$species), levels = c(medians_order))
```

[image: Ordered median plot]